# Difference *was not* and *did not*

Tags: sentence-construction

Is Below sentence construction is correct?

- Input was not flowed into the system (By admin) when he called me. So I asked him to wait*

this is because "to flow" is an intransitive verb so it cannot have a direct object. so we cannot form a passive with an intransitive verb.

Or it should be

- Input did not flow into the system when he called me. So I asked him to wait*

Also,

- Input was not flowed into the system*

Can we use above sentence as an information / Stative? Also can we use "flowed" as verb to be ?

- Window was not opened.
- He was not killed in accident.

Answer (score 1):

> "to flow" is an intransitive verb so it cannot have a direct object. so we cannot form a passive with an intransitive verb.

Right. Or... mostly right. According to wiktionary.org the verb flow has ten different definitions. Seven out of the ten are intransitive which don't take an object, and therefore having an object in the sentence would be an error.
The other definitions such as "to cover with water or other liquid" allow an object. So, it's a case by case basis. "Input" is not a water or liquid though...

> Input was not flowed into the system (By admin) when he called me. So I asked him to wait*

Incorrect.

> Input did not flow into the system when he called me. So I asked him to wait.

Basically correct. See below for more examples though.

> Input was not flowed into the system*

Incorrect.

> Can we use above sentence as "Window was not opened" or "He was not killed in accident".

No. Because those verbs may have a direct object, and can be passive.

If you prefer to use the passive tense with "flow", then try a different verb:

> The input had not been entered into the system (by the admin) when he called me. So I asked him to wait.

Correct. Also "typed in", "submitted".

Comment: *The tube through which the gas was ﬂowed over the source can. be seen to the left and above the source.*  In this sentence *was flowed* is used as passive voice.

Comment: *This sludge was flowed into the river, polluting the water. Thousands of fish had perished in the river recently after this * and what about this *was flowed*

Comment: @user4084 - I find the passive used of flowed just barely acceptable in the specific context of chemical experiments; it sounds completely unidiomatic in the context of information flow.  In fact, googling for the phrase "information was flowed" finds only 25 examples on the entire internet, as opposed to "information flowed", which has 41,000 results.

Comment: @user4084 , updated the answer.

Comment: Sam thanks for the answer . Input aslo has to made flowed by someone like software, system or a person . So object is required

Comment: Also can we use "flowed" as verb to be ?

Answer (score 0):

`Input` is usually `provided to` (or `consumed by`). Do you really have to use `flow`?

Additionally:

`to be + [not] + participle` = passive voice

`to do + [not] + verb` = active voice